# Access Raw JSON from Doctrine ODM/Document

Tags: doctrine-odm

Is there a way to access the raw JSON stored for a document? We have a scenario where a field could be removed from the ODM\Document, but we still may want a way of displaying that data (for historical purposes).

Answer (score 0):

The only place where you can access raw data from MongoDB is [a preLoad](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.0/reference/events.html#preload) event which is fired just before a document is hydrated.